# how to make server accessible from VPN only

Tags: openvpn, ufw, ubuntu-16.04

I have ubuntu 16 vps with openvpn running. I would like to reject all incoming connections expect http and https for /www/. Allow incoming connections only from users which use vpn service running on this VPS. So the question is how to do it? or Where I can read about it? I am completely new to Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPN clients should have different subnet IP addresses from others. So you can use firewall to open HTTP and HTTPS services only to VPN subnet.

Ubuntu 16 uses UFW as its default firewall. So check blow link and `man ufw` for usage.
https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/firewall.html